# Image Gallery in Masonry Grid with random width & random height

Tags: jquery, jquery-masonry

[image: Masonary]

This is my gallery layout. I wanted to arrange images in the above grid style and responsive. It has random width & random height.  But all of the images i have is vertical. So I need help to work on this.

Thanks in advance.

I tried using CSS column-count. This is what I got 
[image]

HTML Code:

```
<div id="container">
    <ul id="myContent">             
        <li><img src="images/1.jpg" alt=""></li>
        <li><img src="images/2.jpg" alt=""></li>
        <li><img src="images/3.jpg" alt=""></li>
        <li><img src="images/4.jpg" alt=""></li>
        <li><img src="images/5.jpg" alt=""></li>
        <li><img src="images/6.jpg" alt=""></li>


    </ul> 
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#container {
    width: 1000px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

#myContent {
    -moz-column-count: 2;
    -moz-column-gap: 10px;
    -webkit-column-count: 2;
    -webkit-column-gap: 10px;
    column-count: 2;
    column-gap: 10px;
    width: 800px;
    list-
}

#myContent img{
    display: inline-block;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
   width:auto;
}
#myContent li:nth-child(n+1):nth-child(-n+4) {text-align:right;}
#myContent li:nth-child(n+5):nth-child(-n+6){text-align:left;}
```

How can I place/arrange the images dynamically? Is there any other way?

Comment: lol. thanks. those are my collections. credits to photographers.

Comment: The hidden message was : "Images are nice, but where is your code?" ;)

Comment: haha :D . "So I need help to work on this." I did not start coding it.

Comment: In that case, I fear there's nothing we can do for you. Our role is not to develop stuff for you. You have to try first, and come here and post your code if you really can't make it, so we can help debug it.

Comment: before posting this question, i gone through masonary grids and some other pinterest style grids but all of them have fixed widths which is not my requirement. So I was not sure those grids should be modified or i can find a better plugin. That is the reason i posted here before coding it

Comment: why can't you put a working sample of your code in jsfiddle. that will help to debug faster

Comment: @strikers http://jsfiddle.net/srikanth_naalla/bh2txhqw/2/

Comment: What do you expect the result for your jsfiddle? I cannot get it.

Comment: @North I'm not expecting anything from my jsfiddle. I just tried is it possible through css or not. I'm not sure how to use jquery to get solved.

Comment: @srikanth_naalla What is expected result ?

Comment: @guest271314 I did not get you.

Comment: @srikanth_naalla Is requirement to arrange images at display similar to image at Question ?

Comment: @srikanth_naalla  http://jsfiddle.net/srikanth_naalla/bh2txhqw/2/ appear to return expected results ?

Comment: @guest271314 see, that was just a try with Column count from css. But i need it dynamically through jquery.

Comment: _"see, that was just a try with Column count from css. But i need it dynamically through jquery. "_ Can create stacksnippets , jsfiddle including `js` , jQuery portions ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82048/discussion-between-srikanth-naalla-and-guest271314).

Answer (score 2):

> see, that was just a try with Column count from css. But i need it
>   dynamically through jquery.

---

> How can i arrange images in this style? All of my images are in the
>   same size. but need to appear random width or random height.

---

Try calling `.each()` on selector `"#myContent li img"` to iterate `img` elements ; set pseudo-random `height` , `width` of each `img` element utilizing `Math.min` , `Math.random`

```js
$("#myContent li img").each(function(i, el) {
  this.height = Math.min(this.height
                         , 1 + Math.floor(Math.random() * this.height * 2));
  this.width = Math.min(this.width
                        , 1 + Math.floor(Math.random() * this.width * 2))
});
```

```css
#container {
  width: 300px;
  margin: 0 0;
}
#myContent {
  -moz-column-count: 2;
  -moz-column-gap: 15px;
  -webkit-column-count: 2;
  -webkit-column-gap: 15px;
  column-count: 2;
  column-gap: 15px;
  width: 800px;
}
#myContent img {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  width: auto;
}
#myContent li:nth-child(n+1):nth-child(-n+4) {
  text-align: right;
}
#myContent li:nth-child(n+5):nth-child(-n+6) {
  text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
  <ul id="myContent">
    <li>
      <img src="http://www.cuded.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/02/Patric-Shaw_17600_664.jpg" alt="">
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/236x/fa/5a/8b/fa5a8b810e97a28b87d7771d09dc4ba5.jpg" alt="">
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="http://www.paulbohman.com/assets/images/photo/vintage/2012/angela_margaux/_8002561.jpg" alt="">
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="http://images4.fanpop.com/image/photos/16100000/Vintage-Fashion-vintage-16124910-450-586.jpg" alt="">
    </li>
    <li>
      <div> <span>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book </span> 
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="http://www.theloveequalsblog.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/03/LUV5846-2.jpg" alt="">
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/736x/94/66/a9/9466a9d9f2f437221462efa5cdf6a1c5.jpg" alt="">
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/bh2txhqw/4/

Comment: Thank you . That was not exactly what i wanted, but it was helpful. Is that possible to create a jquery of a standard layout that should repeat the same pattern.??

Comment: @srikanth_naalla _Not certain interpret "Is that possible to create a jquery of a standard layout that should repeat the same pattern.??"_ correctly ? Can describe "jquery of a standard layout" ? , "should repeat the same pattern" ?

Comment: Please check this image.. They grey boxes are the standard layout of my images, when I upload more that 12 images. the layout should repeat as shown in purple color.  
https://www.dropbox.com/s/hfcepnkkik4ygio/Standard-Layout-03.jpg?dl=0

Comment: @srikanth_naalla _"Please check this image.. They grey boxes are the standard layout of my images, when I upload more that 12 images. the layout should repeat as shown in purple color."_ Gray, purple boxes appear to be arranged identically - only difference appear to be colour ?

Comment: Yes, they are identical. For understanding purpose i just applied a purple color. Please imagine it as a Gallery. The first 11 images (grey color boxes) are arranged in that way. If i have more than 11 images the layout should repeat (like 12-22)

https://www.dropbox.com/s/zdyecupk89iobyb/Standard-Layout-04.jpg?dl=0

Comment: @srikanth_naalla Can create stacksnippets , jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net to demonstrate ?

Comment: I wish I could. unfortunately, am not expert to create own jquery. Am still in beginner level.